# Problems coverting string into const char and then struct hostent

Tags: c++, winsock

I have this code that make an http-webrequest, but I don't know how to add a url to the host const, because every time I do this with the code it shows me this error:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Here is the code:

```
// originally posted to https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH1BG.png
```

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
void connect(string url)
{
  //Adding for the host
  const char *curl = url.c_str();
  WSADATA wsaData;
  //original code
  if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    system("pause");

  }
  SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  struct hostent *host;
  host = gethostbyname(curl);
  SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
  SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
  SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
  cout << "Connecting...\n";
  if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
    cout << "Could not connect";
    system("pause");

  }
  cout << "Connected.\n";
  send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
  char buffer[10000];
  int nDataLength;
  while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] > 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
      cout << buffer[i];
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  closesocket(Socket);
  WSACleanup();
  system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you blindly assume that the return-value from `gethostbyname` is not `NULL`, you should check so that the host-name lookup was successful, before trying to use `host->h_addr`.

> If no error occurs, gethostbyname returns a *pointer* to the hostent structure described above. Otherwise, it returns a *null pointer* and a specific error number can be retrieved by calling `WSAGetLastError`.
>
> src; [**msdn.microsoft.com** - gethostbyname function (windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

---

<sub>**proposed fix**</sub>

```
struct hostent *host;
host = gethostbyname(curl);

if (!host) {
   // hostname lookup failed, handle error
   std::cerr << "hostname error, code: " << WSAGetLastError () << "\n";
   return; // return from function, there's nothing more we can do
}
```

Comment: So.. How should i integrate the fix to the code?
Thnks for the answer

Comment: Just insert the above *if-statement* after the two lines that are a direct copy of what you wrote, if `host` is `NULL`, `if(!host)` will fire and you will end up in the if-block.

Comment: Sorry, im very bad with c++ xD
Should it look like [this](https://gyazo.com/f65bc43fac7c49464a75f6f7e62be2bc)? Or need to add an "else {}"?
if the second, then i should be coverting bad the string to const char*
cause it never shows anything

Comment: @Onelio see the edit, but *stackoverflow* is not a code-writing service; please mark the answer as accepted, if you have follow-up questions you are to ask a new question. You must include something to do in the if-block, `//` denotes the start of a comment.